# setState doesn't update array with firebase object

Tags: reactjs, react-native

So the problem I'm having is that the `setState` method doesn't seem to want to update the state of my array `questions`. But when I use `console.log(returnArr)` the console prints my desired item from firebase.

What I'm I doing wrong?

```js
export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      questions: [],
      current_question: 0
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    var rootRef = firebase.database().ref();
    var ref = rootRef.child("Geography");
    var returnArr = [];

    ref
      .once("value")
      .then(function(snapshot) {
        snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
          var item = childSnapshot.val();
          item.key = childSnapshot.key;

          if (item.key === "2") {
            returnArr.push(item.Question);
            setState = () => ({
              questions: returnArr
            });
            console.log(returnArr);
          }
        });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }

  render() {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setState` is a function you should call, not an object you should assign a new value to.

If you want to use `this` inside the firebase callback function you must either `bind` the function to `this` or use an arrow function. You most likely want to set the array in state after the entire snapshot has been processed.

**Example**

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  // ...

  componentDidMount() {
    firebase
      .database()
      .ref()
      .child("Geography")
      .once("value")
      .then(snapshot => {
        const questions = [];

        snapshot.forEach(childSnapshot => {
          const item = childSnapshot.val();
          item.key = childSnapshot.key;

          if (item.key === "2") {
            questions.push(item.Question);
          }
        });

        this.setState({ questions });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  }

  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not calling setState, you are redefining it.

Change the if to this:

```
if(item.key === '2'){
  returnArr.push(item.Question)
  this.setState({
      questions: returnArr
  });
  console.log(returnArr)

}
```

Also, you probably want to call setState after the forEach has ended. In the way you implemented, setState will be called each time the if code is executed. Moving the setState call out of the forEach will make the setState to be called just once.

Comment: Thanks! I get what you're saying but now I get this error instead:
12:56:21: this.setState is not a function. (In 'this.setState({
            questions: returnArr
          })', 'this.setState' is undefined)